# Upgrading the SQL Server upgrade, any dependencies?

Tags: sql-server, windows-2003-webserver

I want to upgrade the SQL Server 2000 on Windows Server 2003 (sp1) to newer version (2005 or something better)

Can it be done?, also what should i know more on that?

Answer (score 0):

[Resources for Upgrading to SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc936623(SQL.100).aspx)

[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Upgrade Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=f5a6c5e9-4cd9-4e42-a21c-7291e7f0f852&displaylang=en)

[SQL Server 2000 to 2008 Upgrade Whitepaper - Microsoft](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/B/20B90384-F3FE-4331-AA12-FD58E6AB66C2/SQL%20Server%202000%20to%202008%20Upgrade%20White%20Paper.docx)